# docker network create command - swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, lxc, lxc-docker

Below is the command used to create `overlay` network driver for swarm cluster instead of using `bridge` network driver

```
     $ docker network create -d overlay xyz


$ docker network ls                      
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER        SCOPE
9c431bc9fec7        bridge              bridge        local
88a4c6a29fa4        docker_gwbridge     bridge        local
10a4bc649237        host                host          local
o79qllmq86xw        ingress             overlay       swarm
417aca5efd6b        none                null          local
nsteeoxfu9b1        xyz                 overlay       swarm
$
```

---

```
$ docker service create --name service_name --network xyz -p 80:80 --repicas 12 <image>
```

What exactly is the purpose of service command using option `--network xyz`? is this the network namespace driver?

Answer (score 0):

`docker service create --network` is described as `Network attachments` (ref. `docker service create --help`), it is to attach a service to an existing `docker` `network` as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/swarm/networking/#attach-a-service-to-an-overlay-network). You can attach a service to multiple `docker` `networks`.

Comment: docker swarm documentation says this... but not self-explanatory... what exactly is going under the hood?